# Media query min-width 1200px doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to understand how media queries work in css . I'm looking for a bootstrap file and copy `.container` @media queries to a blank css and add colors to see it in live action:

file.css:

```
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color:green;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {width: 750px;background-color:red;}
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
     .container {width: 970px;background-color:blue;}
}
@media (min-width: 1200px ) {
    .container {width: 1170px;background-color:red;}
}
```

index.html

```
<div class="container">Hello</div>
```

When i run it and resize the browser window, the div change colors but never changes to red (1200+ px).

Why is this happening?

EDIT :

In firefox works fine , problem apears in Chrome.

Comment: Working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/hx3y2/. May be in your case it is already have one more media query with same 1200 width and overwritting this styles. Try to use "!important" keyword here.

Comment: This code is working properly. Did you try in a 1200+ px screen?..

Comment: Im tested in chrome and fails, in firefox works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look and test your webpage on

[TestSize](http://testsize.com/)

[ScreenFly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/)

**Your code is working properly.**